# SD card containing personal files is unsupported after phone repairs

Tags: sd-card, motorola-moto-g, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

My Lenovo Moto G4 (Android 6.0.1) died recently. I sent it for repairs, without the SD card I used for internal storage (I don't remember asking for it to be encrypted). The phone just came back, with a complete factory reset.

Inserting my SD card, I was hoping to at least get back the files on it, but I get the "Unsupported SanDisk SD card" message.

When I try to open the SD card with my computer, Windows fails and tells me the card must be formatted.

- Is there a specific procedure to restore files from a SD card formatted for Androids internal storage?
- Is it otherwise possible that my SD card was corrupted when the smartphone died?
- Any idea how to get my files?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but you have to say goodbye to the data stored on it. If you used it as "internal storage", it was encrypted – and the encryption key stored on the device, where it is gone from due to the factory-reset. For details, please see our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info).

Comment: That's one big contra on adoptable-storage. I strongly recommend reading at least the above mentioned tag-wiki before deciding on using it. Too late for you, I know. I blame "marketing" for that, which only underlines the pros and (at least in this case) completely forgets to mention the cons and the pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your files off the SD card using linux. Depending on what format the card was formatted with Windows wont r/w to it without first formatting it.

Comment: Won't work if the card was used as internal storage. See my comment on the question itself: the computer won't be able to read the partition, as it's encrypted. So without the encryption key, not even Linux can get to the files stored on it.